# Get the autogenerated variable of Ivory Google Maps Bundle for symfony 2.3

Tags: javascript, google-maps, symfony, bundle

today I start using the bundle [ivory google maps](https://github.com/egeloen/IvoryGoogleMapBundle) and I find all so simple and very easy, but now i want to do some tries from javascript and for this i need the actual variable of the map, that the bundle auto generated every time i refresh the page, so i can't put in the code the name. So, are any way to search this variable from the javascript? so, travelling the scope of variables or something, or you know another better form to get the current map, isntead of the variable? thanks a lot.

EDIT: I finally found the solution in the bundle page in github, to set the personal name of variable in the javascript you need to use this function setJavascriptVariable and for acces from ajvascript you need to use _container.map